# Embed IPython with pylab enabled

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

IPython shell has the `enable_pylab` method. So, in interactive mode it looks like that:

```
In [1]: ipshell = get_ipython()

In [2]: ipshell.enable_pylab()
Out[2]: ('tk', 'TkAgg', [])

In [3]: pi
Out[3]: 3.141592653589793
```

I'd expect the following code should run an interactive IPython shell with `pi` in its namespace:

```
import IPython.terminal.embed as embed
ipshell = embed.InteractiveShellEmbed()
ipshell.enable_pylab()
ipshell()
```

But it doesn't.

I suspect the problem is that the `enable_pylab` is called before `ipshell` is being initialized. It seems `enable_pylab` updates the `user_ns`, but perhaps this is overridden by the initializer..?

If that's the case, can I somehow initialize the shell without embedding it, then enable pylab, and then embed it?

I am using Python 2.7, IPython 3.0.0, pylab 1.9.2.